# How does this distribution make sense?

Tags: work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNFH9.jpg

I’m talking about the mg*abs(yf-yi) = mgyi- mgyf. Shouldn’t it be mgyf - mgyi when you distribute it???

Comment: Please typeset your question rather than refer to an image so your post is self contained.

Answer (score 0):

The book explicitly states that "we have to be careful with the signs". The expression $mg|y_f-y_i|$ is equal to $mgy_f-mgy_i$ if $y_f>y_i$ and is equal to $mgy_i-mgy_f$ if $y_f<y_i$. In this particular problem the second inequality holds so you have to reverse the terms so that the final answer is positive.